# Updating Daily TimeFrame chart with Pine script

Tags: pine-script

All,

I have a script that runs in Daily Time frame. But as it runs Daily in Daily Time Frame, the End Of Day Values of that Day are updated only when the next day Candle opens.

Is there a way to simulate Tomorrows candle or run the script considering it is a Tomorrow, so today's values are considered in script?

or is there any other way to do, so today's Volume activity is included in Eod? As in Daily Time frame , today's volume activity is getting calculated ONLY when next day candle opens.

Thanks for the assistance.

Trying to update the chart EoD on 'Daily' Time Frame

Comment: Is this a `strategy` or `indicator`?

Comment: Hi, It is Indicator. Your help greatly appreciated. Pls suggest any idea.

Comment: Could you please share your code?

Comment: Pls see below. Though Market close, in Daily Bar the last Candle shows as 'False' for 'barstate.islastconfirmedhistory'. So today's Trading volume is not getting considered. Any Suggestions?                                                                                                                             if barstate.islastconfirmedhistory
    label.new(bar_index, low, style=label.style_label_up,
         color=color.red, textcolor=color.white,
         text="history\nbar")

Comment: barstate.islastConfirmedHistory Bar comes as false for last even after Market closed ONLY for Daily Timeframe in Trading View. For all other TimeFrames the last Candle comes as True as expected.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code there.